# Laravel : GuzzleHttp Error guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using laravel passport for API authentication in my project, I register a user and send a post request by `GuzzleHttp\Client` to `AccessTokenController@issueToken` for getting access token but when I test it in `Postman` it doesn't work.

Error :

```
 "message": "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 4009 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)",
    "exception": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\BR\\PhpstormProjects\\Arayshgary\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php",
    "line": 185,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\BR\\PhpstormProjects\\Arayshgary\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "createRejection",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory",
            "type": "::"
        },
```

my code:

```
Route::post('/register','API\User\AuthController@register');
```

register method:

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'=> 'required|string',
            'last_name'=> 'required|string',
            'email'=> 'required|string',
            'password'=> 'required|string',
            'status'=> 'string',
            'verified'=> 'string',
            'register_type'=> 'string',
        ]);

        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->last_name = $request->last_name ;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password= bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        $client = new Client([
            'timeout'  => 5.0,
        ]);
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '4',
                'client_secret' => 'LPdfy5ZnhIvlA1QUu1e1Wh33zePnS65hm4b600aJ',
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => '',
                'provider'=>'barbers'
            ],
        ]);

        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    }
```

I try it with `Curl` but it doesn't work.

```
$response = Curl::to('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token')
            ->withData( [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '4',
                'client_secret' => 'LPdfy5ZnhIvlA1QUu1e1Wh33zePnS65hm4b600aJ',
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => '',
                'provider'=>'barbers',
                ])
            ->enableDebug('C:\Users\BR\Desktop\logFile.txt')
            ->withContentType('application/json')
            ->post();
        return ['data'=>json_decode((string) $response, true)];
```

route list:

```
POST      | oauth/token                             | oauth.token                | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken           | passport-administrators,throttle
```

and I use Passport Multiple-Auth https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/161#issuecomment-299690583

Comment: it seems you're knocking the door on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token` however nobody is there to answer it. Are you sure that your service is working?

Comment: if it isn't working in Postman or PHP, what makes you so sure it's a problem with your code?

Comment: How can I know the service is work properly?